# Present UISplitViewController in UITabBarController app by UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` which is called by the tap on `UITabBarItem`. Everything works fine unless I need to call the `UISplitController` from the other places in my app by clicking on cell for example. I can't push it or present it modal.

Is there a way to do this ? I know that the design of the app is not perfect but I can't change it unfortunately. So I need to present the `UITabBarViewController` by pressing some element on other tabs of the app.

Answer (score 0):

you can not push or present uisplitviewcontroller because it must be as root of application.you can create custom splitview using your custom view controllers
up to my knowledge that i know....

Comment: but it works as a tabbaritem in tabbarviewcontroller - may be there is the way to implement this..

Comment: i think for splitviewcontroller to work it must be as root to window but you cant try by implementing delegates in view controller of splitviewcontrller may be it will work i dont know actully i also will try this

Comment: I have been looking at this same issue the past few days. There are many apps in the app store with this same functionality (IE. Yelp app)...

Comment: I believe - I need to implement custom tabbarcontroller and splitviewcontroller